# Jquery and React together for html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, server-side-rendering

i've got a theme for a pizza ordering app. My rest api is ready. But i've some problems with frontend.

Theme functions runs with jquery and lots of jquery written. React renders page after loading so jquery won't run with it.

so two things in my mind

Can server side rendering solve my problem? (partly easy for me)

or

write web app with jquery (lots lots of hard to make for me)

what really can i do ?

Comment: i'm currently researching nextjs. still might need help

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code?

Comment: we decided to change template. probably jqueryless one. thnx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, if you can rewrite the code completely in React, it'll be better. But if you want to reuse your existing code, here's a [helpful link](http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/)

Comment: my boss changed the project template now. i think we're going to rewrite jquery insde react components. thnx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can map theme objects to react JSX component with appropriate scaffolding and style.

Comment: my boss changed the project template now. i think we're going to rewrite jquery insde react components. thnx for answer.